# Rails - get result with 0 for non-existence value in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using this query to get products with prices.

```sql
select sku, price from products where sku in ('001', '002', '003');
```

The expected result:

```json
{
  '001': 50,
  '002': 40,
  '003' : 0 // if the sku doesn't exit, want to set price 0
}
```

But the above query only returns products that exist in the database so I need to loop the result and add 0 if the product doesn't exist in the result.

Is there any way to get the expected result without looping in Rails or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a list of the target sku-s (the `t` CTE) and join it with `products`. Use `string_to_array` for building the list to make the query suitable for parameterizing.

```sql
-- '001,002,003' is the list of products to query
with t(sku) as 
(
 select unnest(string_to_array('001,002,003', ','))
)
select json_object_agg(t.sku, coalesce(p.price, 0))
from t 
left outer join products p on t.sku = p.sku;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e79590/2)

Parameterized and w/o CTE:

```sql
select json_object_agg(t.sku, coalesce(p.price, 0))
from unnest(string_to_array(?, ',')) t(sku)
left outer join products p on t.sku = p.sku;
```